# Big query Storage API permission issue

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I am using a service account to write data to Big query using big query storage API using java SDK, and I see the below error. Do I need to provide any other roles to the service account?

Error: 00:44:38 | Error: com.google.api.gax.rpc.PermissionDeniedException: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: PERMISSION_DENIED: Request had insufficient authentication scopes.

Current Roles to the service account: BigQuery Admin,  BigQuery Data Owner, BigQuery Data Editor

code snippet:

```
        Map<String, Object> metadata = new HashMap<>();
        metadata.put("table_name", "MetaData");
        metadata.put("timestamp", Instant.now().toString());
        metadata.put("is_processed", false);
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(metadata);
        TableName parentTable = TableName.of("test", "test", "MetaData");

        WriteStream stream = WriteStream.newBuilder().setType(WriteStream.Type.COMMITTED).build();

        CreateWriteStreamRequest createWriteStreamRequest =
                CreateWriteStreamRequest.newBuilder()
                        .setParent(parentTable.toString())
                        .setWriteStream(stream)
                        .build();
        WriteStream writeStream = bigQueryWriteClient.createWriteStream(createWriteStreamRequest);

        // Use the JSON stream writer to send records in JSON format.
        // For more information about JsonStreamWriter, see:
        // https://googleapis.dev/java/google-cloud-bigquerystorage/latest/com/google/cloud/bigquery/storage/v1/JsonStreamWriter.html
        JsonStreamWriter streamWriter = JsonStreamWriter.newBuilder(writeStream.getName(), writeStream.getTableSchema()).build();
        JSONArray arr = new JSONArray();
        arr.put(jsonObject);
        // Append asynchronously for increased throughput.
        ApiFuture<AppendRowsResponse> future = streamWriter.append(arr, 1);
        ApiFutures.addCallback(
                future, new AppendCompleteCallback(), MoreExecutors.directExecutor());
```

Comment: Do you reach federated tables that access a Google Workspace document (drive or google sheet)

Comment: I didn't get you @guillaumeblaquiere

Comment: Do you have only BigQuery Native Tables?

Comment: yes, we only have Native tables @guillaumeblaquiere

Comment: Can you refer to this [doc](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/authentication/service-account-file#loading_credentials_from_a_file) to load service account credentials in your file? Let me know if it's helpful or not?

Comment: @PrajnaRaiT no change after loading from a file

Comment: Do you query from Compute Engine?

Comment: No I am actually querying from a VM that's in our enterprise data center @guillaumeblaquiere

Comment: Can you share how you create the `bigQueryWriteClient`?

Comment: Can you check whether your service account is having these [permissions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/dataset-access-controls#before_you_begin) to access dataset. Also can you try creating credentials with scopes using the this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/samples/bigquery-auth-drive-scope#code-sample)?

Comment: We figured out the issue is with the enterprise proxy that is blocking the call to BQ. thanks @guillaumeblaquiere

Comment: Hi @RaviTeja, Is your issue resolved? If so, can you add resolution steps as the answer?

Answer (score 0):

@Ravi Teja, As you have mentioned in the comment that the issue is with the enterprise proxy which is blocking the call to BigQuery.

Enterprise proxy is an intermediary server separating end users from the websites they browse. Proxy servers provide varying levels of functionality, security, and privacy depending on your use case, needs, or company policy.

Posting the answer as community wiki for the benefit of the community that might encounter this use case in the future.

Feel free to edit this answer for additional information.